# Codeigniter query for selecting sum of multiple columns with where conditions on each row

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have made this function to get sum of population percent based on group_id as 1,2 and 3 but its not working

```
public function ethnicity($value='')
        {
            $this->db->select('SUM(population_percent) as p1 where group_id=1,SUM(population_percent) as p2 where group_id=2,SUM(population_percent) as p3 where group_id=3', FALSE);
            $this->db->from('ethnic_group');
            $data=$this->db->get()->row_array();
                return $data;
        }
```

Comment: you cant pass `where` in `select` refer CI active record guide.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `$this->db->select()` you are writing the 'select' part of a query. To write the 'where' you should use `$this->db->where('group_id=3')`.

In case you want to write an entire query and tell CodeIgniter to run it, you can use `$this->db->query($sql)` with `$sql` beign the actual query you want to run [as seen in the documentation here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#regular-queries).

So I think it should look something like this:

```
 $sql = 'your query here';
 $data = $this->db->query($sql)->row_array();
 return $data;
```

Comment: sir i have data stored in table on the bases of group_id and there are three groups i want to get sum of population coulmn for all these three group in a single query.

Comment: I think Devsi Odedra's answer solves the query and the CodeIgniter problem. Try that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `IF` or `CASE` when need to do `sum` with this type of condition

**Use this query**

```
public function ethnicity($value='')
{
    $sql = "SELECT  
              SUM(CASE WHEN group_id='1' THEN population_percent ELSE 0 END) p1,
              SUM(CASE WHEN Type='2' THEN population_percent ELSE 0 END) p2,
              SUM(CASE WHEN Type='3' THEN population_percent ELSE 0 END) p3,
            FROM ethnic_group LIMIT 1";


    $data = $this->db->query($sql)->row_array();
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: you can accept it if it is useful, so other can also refer it.